# iOS App for Distribution with Profile

Tags: ios, enterprise, device, in-house-distribution

I'm working on an app that requires users to install a profile in order to allow us to have more control over their device. There are several apps like this on the app store. If I intended to distribute my app via the App Store, then direct users to install a profile, am I technically doing a in-house distribution or is it called something else? I understand non-enterprise dev accounts are limit to 100 devices and I'm concerned about that limitation.

Thanks,
Howie